# tf gradients of multiple losses

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose I have a multiple losses defined as

```
losses = ... # a tensor with shape: (10,)
```

Now I want to find the gradient each loss over a weight `w`

```
for i in range(len(10)):
    grad[i] = tf.gradients(losses[i], w)
```

Now, can I do this without the above `for` loop but directly?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the tf.map_fn to do map any arbitrary function across the first dimension of a tensor. So something like this should do the trick:

```py
def get_grads(x):
  return tf.gradients(x, w)

tf.map_fun(get_grads, losses)
```

Comment: I just tried. But because losses is a tensor, this one does not work at the moment. It seems to need some more trick.

Comment: what error did you receive? I can't see why it wouldn't work. Are you able to give an example i can execute?

Comment: Cannot use 'map/while/gradients/f_count_1' as input to 'map/while/gradients/f_count' because they are in different while loops. See info log for more details.

Comment: The code I ran is almost the same as your example code. w is just a list of trainable variables and losses is a tensor of multiple losses.